# Increment value depending on months count -SQL that isn't working

Tags: sql, .net

Employee annual leave limit per years is 30. Per month 2.5 is added as a annual leave balance based on his joining date.

For example say employee completed 3 months his annual leave balance count should be 7.5.

```
1st month - 2.5
2nd month - 5
3rd month - 7.5
```

How to achieve this using sql / .net

Regards,

Comment: Calculate number of months from joining *2.5

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: What is not working, please include your try.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (sysdate - job_start_date) / 30 * 2.5 anlBalance from myEmpTable
```

and to round up the balance you can use `ceil` and to round down `floor`

```
select ceil((sysdate - job_start_date) / 30 * 2.5) anlBalance from myEmpTable
select floor((sysdate - job_start_date) / 30 * 2.5) anlBalance from myEmpTable
```